# Symfony - make:form is not submit

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a registration form with a FormType here **RegisterFormType**,
here is my signup function

```
#[Route('/inscription', name: 'app_signup', methods: ['GET|POST'])]
    public function signup(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        dd($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()); // return FALSE
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
        }
        return $this->render('security/signup.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Here is my **RegisterFormType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\Length(min: 2, minMessage: 'Le prénom doit avoir au minimum 2 caractères')
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'label' => 'Prénom'
            ])
            ->add('username', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\Length(min: 3, minMessage: "Le nom d'utilisateur doit avoir au minimum 3 caractères")
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'label' => 'Nom d\'utilisateur'
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\Email()
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'options' => [
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]
                ],
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Mot de passe',
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Mot de passe (confirmation)'
                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas'
            ])
        ;
    }
```

And finnally, here is my view

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="form-row w-75 mx-auto p-4">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    {{ form_row(form.username) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-center p-2 mt-2 mx-auto">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-50" value="S'inscrire"></button>
                    <span class="small d-block"><a href="{{ path('app_login') }}" class="base-link text-success">Déjà inscrit ?</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But for some reasons I ignore, the submission of the form is not completed, but if I replace plainPassword for password field its working fine. Can someone tell me why please ?
Here is my **EntityListener** for **plainPassword** field

```
class UserListener
{
    private UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function prePersist(User $user)
    {
        $this->hashPassword($user);
    }

    public function preUpdate(User $user)
    {
        $this->hashPassword($user);
    }

    private function hashPassword(User $user)
    {
        if (!is_null($user->getPlainPassword())){
            $hashPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($hashPassword);
            $user->setPlainPassword(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can user console commands to generate these files: For logging in `php bin/console make:auth` and for registration: `php bin/console make:registration`

Comment: You can see the errors in the form submitted by adding this to the controller. $form->getErrors(true);